# Counting NULL values and Total Records

Tags: sql, count, union, common-table-expression

I created the following query using a common table expression and several unions to achieve something that may be more easily performed otherwise. I have a dimension table "zc_order_status" that contains data keyed by "order_status" and "name". Fact table "orders" contains data keyed by order_id and includes order_status and other various pieces of data.

With respect to the fact table, my goal is to display a count of order_id grouped by order_status (for all order_status, even those that do not appear in the fact table). I would also like to display a count of order_id where order_status is NULL. Finally, I would like to display a count of all order_id, regardless of order_status (similar to a rollup).

I am able to return the desired values using this query, but I am interested in improving performance and streamlining the process.

Here's the query:

```
WITH sampledata
    (order_status, name)
AS
    (SELECT
         DISTINCT
         order_status
        ,name
     FROM
        zc_order_status
    )

SELECT
     zc.order_status
    ,zc.name
    ,COUNT(op.order_status) AS statuscount
FROM
    sampledata  AS zc
LEFT JOIN
    orders      AS op   ON zc.order_status = op.order_status
GROUP BY
     zc.name
    ,zc.order_status

UNION

SELECT
     999 AS order_status
    ,'UNKNOWN' AS name
    ,COUNT(order_id) AS statuscount
FROM
    orders
WHERE
    order_status IS NULL

UNION

SELECT
     9999 AS order_status
    ,'ALL RECORDS' AS name
    ,COUNT(order_id) AS statuscount
FROM
    orders
```

Comment: which dbms are you using? sql server, mysql, oracle, postgres, newsqldbms?

Comment: I am using sql server. I should have mentioned that up front. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can't say how much a performance difference you might see, but try this:

```sql
with sampledata (order_status, name) as (
  select distinct 
      order_status
    , name
    from zc_order_status
  union all
  select 
      999 as order_status
    , 'unknown' as name
  )

  select 
      case when grouping (zc.order_status)=1 then 9999
           else zc.order_status 
           end as order_status
    , case when grouping (zc.name)=1 then 'all records'
           else zc.name 
           end as name
    , count(op.*) as statuscount
    from sampledata as zc
      left join orders as op
        on zc.order_status = coalesce(op.order_status, 999)
    group by grouping sets (
      (zc.order_status, zc.name)
      ,()
      )
    order by order_status;
```

Comment: Thank you for an alternative approach. I tested this method with a couple of my tables, and it seems to be comparable in performance. It is always nice to have another option should the need arise. Perhaps I wasn't too far off from the start...